# Hide div if value is undefined or blank (Angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have the following. If i do a console.log($scope.variable), i get 2 values of it at different times on the console.

It shows undefined and '' at the console.

I want to hide a div on basis of this value. I do the following

```
<div ng-hide="$scope.variable== undefined || $scope.variable = ''>
  Hide this section
</div>
```

It should be able to hide the section since the values are either undefined and '' at all cases. However the div still shows at the UI. Am i missing any constraint or not putting the condition check properly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ng-show` should never be used.It will load view in value and just hides it by setting `css` property `display:none`.  Instead use `ng-if`

```
<div ng-if="variable != null"></div>
or

<div ng-if="variable === null>
  Hide this section
</div>
```

Comment: I disagree that it should never be used. There are instances where hiding an element with CSS is the better choice, e.g. if you are hiding and showing elements in a list based off of user input. Why do you say that it's bad practice?

Comment: @Greg You may be correct. But if that list contains multiple nested list. Than what you will prefer? There is always an exceptional cases but in above question case, we should go with ng-if.

Comment: @Greg What if list data is coming from controller and is dynamic? with ng-show, it may not get compiled.

Answer (score 4):

```
<div ng-show="variable != null"></div>
```

or

```
<div ng-hide="variable == null>
  Hide this section
</div>
```

You could use ng-if in this case, which would result in better performance,

```
 <div ng-if="variable == null">
      Hide this section
 </div>
```

Comment: Damn. i thought null and undefined are 2 different things.. this worked. thanks

Comment: `Null` and `undefined` are 2 different things.

Comment: Null and underfined are different , but in this case you can use the above method or you can directly check for undefined instead of null.